# Is int (built in data types) a class in c++?

Tags: c++, class

Is `int` a `class`?

Please consider below code

```
#include"iostream"

using namespace std;

class test{
public:
    int a;

    test(int x)
    {
        cout<<"In test Constructor"<<endl;
        a = x;
    }
};

int main()
{
    test *obj = new test(10);// Constructor get called 
int *x = new int(10);    // Expecting the same if "int" is a class
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `delete new int[5]` is undefined behaviour (not necessarily a memory leak). Also, no, `int` is not a class (but `new int(10)` does initialise the `int` to `10`).

Comment: Stop editing the question dramatically. Either it's `int(5)` or `int[5]`. Make up your mind if you want help!

Comment: @LuchianGrigore : ok...now please consider below things as 1.int x = new int[10]; its an array and in this case deleted should be from delete[]? 2.As i know new will allocate the memory but it will call constructor of a class then in that what is int whether a consturtor gets called or not?

Comment: 1. yes 2. `int` is a built-in type. Not a class. That's just how you allocate dynamic memory.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore please check the modified question ...sorry to modify but it will give a clear picture...

Comment: What do you mean how it will work. The first is the syntax for creating a class dynamically. The second is the syntax for an `int`... there's no constructor for int because it's not a class...

Comment: @LuchianGrigore I mean to say if you have seen the code first one is calling a constructor of a class test but in the case of int as you said that int is not a class and dont have constructor then how its get initialized from what method?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22910/discussion-between-amit-0440-and-luchian-grigore)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, `int` is not a `class`, and `int x = new int(10);` is not valid C++ syntax.

```
int* x = new int(5);
...
...
delete x;
```

This just creates a pointer to an `int` and `new int(5)` is a way to initialize a pointer.

> And the correct way should be delete[] x;

No, because you allocated it with `new`, not `new[]`. The correct way though is `int x = 5;` or `int x(5);` - avoid dynamic allocation unless truly necessary.

Comment: ... and `delete[]` is for arrays or data allocated by `new []`

Comment: i have edited the question for syntax but the question is still remain same.

Comment: @Luchian, Y U NO `unique_ptr`? Too basic question?

Comment: @Amit0440 not really, the syntax completely changes the question.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore I have a question `int` I mean basic data-types are not implemented as class that's why Java(and C++) is not purely object oriented language **?** I am asking for Java

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan then ask a question and tag it Java... Note that java AFAIK has both int and Int

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: If you have a question about Java, feel free to ask one on your own. But please try and search for that topic _before_ posting a question.

Answer (score 2):

```
Is int a class in c++?
```

No. Because `int` cannot be inherited, cannot have function defined within its scope and lacks so many properties which a class must have.

> If we say : `int *x = new int(5);` Will it call a constructor of
>   int?

It will initialized the new integer with `5`. It at least gives the effect of constructor. But to be pedantic, it doesn't call constructor. For the case of `new int[10]` it doesn't call constructor and the value of `10` ints are implementation defined. However `new int[10]()` will value initialize (i.e. 0) to all the 10 ints.

> And the correct way should be delete[] x

No. The correct pairing for any data type is `malloc()/free()`, `new/delete`, `new[]/delete[]` and `new(<placement>) T/ ~T()`. Rest all are undefined behaviors.

Comment: ok.....then how actually int x = new int(10); works?

Comment: it doesn't works at all, because `new` operator returns a pointer

Comment: @Amit0440 ` int* x = new int(10);` works because the language rules say that is a valid way to dynamically allocate an int with value 10.

Answer (score 1):

No, the basic types of C++ (`char`, `int`, `long`, `float`, `double`, etc.) are not classes.

However, the language has been designed in such a way that the difference can mostly be ignored. The most important differences are

- The basic types can't have members. Classes can (and usually will).
- The basic types can't be specified as a base-class.

Comment: ok...but as i know c came before c++ so int was already there and at that time there would not be a class concept at all....then The basic types can't have members meaning?

Comment: @Amit0440: The C heritage does not mean that much. C++ could have been defined in such a way that it was both backwards compatible with C *and* that all types were classes. The "can't have members" part means that constructs like `int i=42; i.toString()` are invalid in C++.

Answer (score 0):

`int`, `float`, `char` all are not a `class` in cpp.
You can not type the following:
`int x=new int(10);`

Even if you consider a class here:
the following are not valid:
`Class x=new Class(10);`

```
Class x=new Class(10);//"new " not "new ...[]"because,
                       // It is just a single object not array.
...
delete x;//Not delete[] x;because x is not array
```

Your expectation is right, but if only when `int` is a class, but it isn't

Comment: i can write the following: `int *x=new int(10);` ...

Comment: @govindo but in above case construtor of class x gets called similarly for int will it be something like that?

Comment: @Amit0440 sorry I accidently typed the '*' sign

Comment: @govindo but still if you take like Class *x = new Class(10) then ?

Comment: If we call `Class *x=new Class(10);` then it creates a pointer x of the type `Class` and is intialized with `new` operator and calling the `Class(int)` constructor of the `class Class`

Comment: @govind please check the modified question