# How can a vector of integers hold objects if an integer is not a class?

Tags: c++, class, object, oop, vector

While I was reading C++ primer fifth edition I came across this definition of a vector:

> A vector is a collection of objects, all of which have the same type.
> Every object in the collection has an associated index, which gives
> access to that object. A vector is often referred to as a container
> because it “contains” other objects.

If I have a vector of integer values then what class do all these objects belong? Because "int" is not a class as these answers from this link already explain:

[Is int (built in data types) a class in c++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14378321/is-int-built-in-data-types-a-class-in-c)

I also came across the concept of "Data Objects" from IBM, are these the objects that the vectors hold in this case? Because I have been reading this concept of "Data object" a lot and it still puzzles me. And even if it is the object that the vectors hold, my question still remains: what class does it belong?

Comment: The vector holds objects of the type int. What is unclear?

Comment: `int` is a *type*.  `std::vector` holds objects of a type.

Comment: But int is not a class then how can I have an object of int?

Comment: An object in C++ does not need to be of a class type. In C++ objects can be of any type, which includes fundamental types such as `int`

Comment: You seem to be mixing knowledge from other languages and tranferring it to c++. The same word can mean different things in different contexts. Who says an object must be a class? Here is a [c++ definition](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/object) of object. Maybe that will clear things up for you.

Comment: int variable is an object: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48026922/is-an-int-variable-an-object-according-to-the-c-standard

Comment: The term *object* has a general meaning in C++. Built-in types can be considered as objects too. See [Object](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/object) for more info.

Comment: So the problem is that I'm confused about the very  concept of  objects in c++. I'll take  a look at the link you sent me and thanks so much for your time and precious informations!

Comment: I notice another confusion: "Object" does not imply "OOP". It's the same word but used with different meanings in different contexts.

Comment: The `class` keyword simply introduces a *user defined type*. A type `int` doesn't need a `class` description because the user doesn't define it, the compiler does.

Comment: `std::vector` is a *templated class*, and templates can be instantiated on any type; they are not limited to only being instantiated on class-types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I have a vector of integer values then what class do all these objects belong?

No class at all. The elements of a vector of integers are objects of the integer type. Integer types are fundamental types.

Comment: So is this object also a Data Object? This would clarify a lot of things to me

Comment: @Isaias What do you mean by Data Object? There is no concept by such name in the C++ language.

Comment: I saw it at this topic from IBM. Would you mind explain it to me? 

https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.4.0?topic=odod-overview-data-objects

Comment: @Isaias As far as I can tell, what IBM is calling "data objects" are called just "objects" in the C++ language.